# BGP prefix-list and network statement question

Tags: cisco, routing, router, bgp, network

Recently I ran across a router with an interesting configuration.  It had `network <IP>`, `network <IP> mask <mask>` and `neighbor <IP> prefix-list <list> out` commands, all for the same network.

Can anyone think of a reason for this?  Is there a reason to have both a `network <IP> mask <mask>` statement and a `neighbor <IP> prefix-list <list> out` statement?

Is there something that the one does that the other doesn't?

On this site, they have the following configuration:

```
   ip prefix-list Summary permit 172.31.0.0/16 le 20
   !
   router bgp 65001
   neighbor 10.1.1.1 prefix-list Summary out
```

Would this configuration work without a `network` statement?  Would my example configuration above work without the `prefix-list` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A prefix list doesn't actually advertise prefixes; it permits or denies prefixes that that the router *can* advertise (or use received prefixes, depending on the direction). The network statements will advertise the prefixes (assuming the *exact* routes exist in the routing table).

It appears that the configuration will let only prefixes smaller than `/20` to be advertised. This is sometimes used because ISPs will only let smaller prefixes to be advertised on the public Internet. Most ISPs will not advertise any prefix longer than `/24`, and some ISPs many not even allow prefixes as long as that.

Comment: So in my first example, I could have `network 0.0.0.0` and then `neighbor <IP> prefix-list <list> out` with the list containing my company's IP block.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The _exact_ prefix of `0.0.0.0` would need to exist in your routing table, but it is unlikely that an ISP would allow you to advertise a default prefix like that. A network statement will only advertise what already exists in your routing table, and it must be an _exact_ match. You could use `aggregate-address` to advertise a smaller prefix than you have in the routing table, but you need to make sure that you control the entire smaller prefix, or your ISP will not allow you to advertise the aggregate.

Comment: So BGP is different from OSPF where you can do [`network 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 area <area-id>`](http://blog.ipspace.net/2007/07/be-smart-when-using-ospf-network.html)?

Comment: The OSPF network statement tells OSPF which interfaces to include in the OSPF process; it does not tell OSPF what network to advertise. The BGP network statement tells BGP what network to advertise, but only if it already exist in the routing table.